# Size of db lotus notes

Tags: database, size, lotus-notes

I need suggestion regarding maximum size for a db lotus notes highly volatil, i.e. an application based on a db of 8+ Gb accessed by 20 users in average inserting attachments and running scripts.

tks !!

Answer (score 4):

There are limits to the size of a Notes Database (sorry Ken). See the Notes Help "[Table of Notes and Domino known limits](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTES_AND_DOMINO_KNOWN_LIMITS.html)" and T[echnote #1308379](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21308379).

The most important ones are:

- Database size: The maximum OS file size limit -- (up to 64GB)
- Fields in a database: ~ 3000 (limited to ~ 64K total length for all field names). You can enable the database property "Allow more fields in database" to get up to 22,893 uniquely-named fields in the database.
- Views in a database: No limit; however, as the number of views increases, the length of time to display other views also increases
- Documents in a view: Up to the maximum size of the database

Ususally the "limiting" factors for an application are view rebuild and full text index times, as Ken suggested.
You may want to checkout [Andre Guirards postings on the topic of performance](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/bpmpblog.nsf/archive?openview&title=Performance&type=cat&cat=Performance&sort=I) as well as his white paper [Performance basics for IBM Lotus Notes developers](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27012441) and the [Domino Wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/xpViewRecent.xsp?searchValue=performance).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but there's theoretically no limit to the size of a Notes database.  Years ago I remember hearing at Lotusphere they had tested a database at 64GBs and it worked.

That said, there will likely be some issues with view indexes growing large, and long waits for refreshing views.

Comment: I believe this is correct (at least I have also heard that claim, made by IBM) even though they may have posted 64 GB as the limit.  It appears that they simply posted that as the limit because it was the largest size they have tested.

Answer (score 1):

In the link below you can find the limitations that concern the Lotus Notes Databases as they come from IBM and stated also from leyrer.

[Limits of Lotus Notes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/fram_limits_of_notes_r.html)

However, in our company we are working heavily with Lotus Notes databases and our databases our growing very fast mostly due to attachments that can be documents, spreadsheets, images, etc. The solution that we implemented in order to avoid reaching the size limits was to have normally the application and attach to it databases for the attachments. In this way the attachments are not stored to the main application, but to the attached dbs. You can create as many as you can. For example you can have the following:

1. MyApp.nsf - Main application
2. MyAppAttach1.nsf - Attached
3. MyAppAttach2.nsf - Attached

In this way we can also control how much the dbs will grow. I hope that this can help you in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For large databases, it may be important to think about a strategy for archiving documents once they are no longer being actively processed.  You don't mention how many documents are created/edited/deleted every day, or how large the average document is; but if it is 8GB now, how large will it be next month, or next year?  Depending on the factors martin listed in his answer, this could become a concern long before you reach the 64 GB supported limit, and it is better to be prepared in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is, create an archive database and reduce the size of the main database. In the next step you should write some process in order to archive the documents weekly or monthly according to your needs.